# What does this sentence mean from "The woman in the window"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

> she is a Bad Cop, no doubt about it, and with disappointment **I realize that Little's aw-shucks shtick must be just smoke**

What does the line in bold mean - *aw-shucks shtick must be just smoke*.

This is from "The woman in the window".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I realize that Little's unsophisticated and sweet mannerisms must be just fake routine designed to confuse me*

> **Aw Shucks**
>   : being or marked by an unsophisticated, self-conscious, or self-effacing manner *an aw-shucks grin.*
>   - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aw-shucks

> **schtick**
>   1 : a usually comic or repetitious performance or routine : bit
>   2 : one's special trait, interest, or activity 
>   - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schtick

> **blow smoke** mainly AMERICAN.
>   If someone blows smoke they deliberately confuse or deceive you. I just can't shake the feeling that he's up to something. Sounds to me like he's blowing smoke. 
>   - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+smoke

> **smokescreen**
>   something that hides the truth about someone's intentions:
>   *Instead of doing something about the problem, the city council is hiding behind a smokescreen of bureaucracy.*
>   - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smokescreen